# REACT API PROJECT: TypeError: Cannot read property 'small' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

With React I'm creating a cryptocurrency analysis tool with data from the CoinGecko API. I am having trouble with getting images from this API onto my app. Here is the json file from the api: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin?tickers=false&market_data=false&community_data=false&developer_data=false&sparkline=false

I am trying to get the `image.small` data, but it is not working. Do anyone know how to fix this? Much appreciated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import "./CoinInfo.css";

const CoinInfo = ({ match }) => {
    const [coinData, setCoinData] = useState([]);
    const [coinHistory, setCoinHistory] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const coinDataRequest = axios.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${match.params.id}?localization=false&tickers=true&market_data=false&community_data=false&developer_data=false&sparkline=false`)
        const coinHistoryRequest = axios.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${match.params.id}/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=max`);
        axios.all([coinDataRequest, coinHistoryRequest])
        .then(
            axios.spread((coinDataResponse, coinHistoryResponse) => {
                setCoinData(coinDataResponse.data);
                setCoinHistory(coinHistoryResponse.data);
            })
            )
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }, [match.params.id])
    
    return (
        <div className="app-contents-container">
            <div className="coin-info-container">
                <div className="coin-info-introduction-container">
                    <div className="coin-info-logo-title-container">
                        <div className="coin-info-logo-container">
                            <img src={coinData.image.small} alt="Bitcoin logo"></img>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="coin-info-price-container">
                        <p>{coinData.categories}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="coin-info-tokenomics-container">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CoinInfo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major problems what I could find in your code, let me explain one by one.

Initially `coinData` is an array, probably you need an `{}` instead in `useState` as firstly:

```
const [coinData, setCoinData] = useState({});
```

Also the data is arriving *asynchronously* which takes time thus you need check the `coinData.image` for `null` or `undefined` as:

```
{ coinData.image && <img src={coinData.image.small} alt="Bitcoin logo"></img> }
```